# Full form of SKU in supportedRuntime in C#

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5

I am just wondering whats the full form of SKU in supportedRuntime in startup under compilation. I know the term in general means Stock Keeping Unit. But I was searching through the net most blogs and even MSDN for its full form. Anybody can help me please ?

If someone asks me, I should be able to say this as a developer, thats why I am curious to know :)

Comment: I too had the same problem. I Searched internet like anything for the SKU attribute full form. The closest thing i found for it is "Security Kernel Unit". I hope that's the correct answer.

Answer (score -3):

please read the msdn help for the entire form of  element:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4atty68.aspx