# What does SKU stands for?

Tags: .net, configuration, versioning

MSDN says that `<supportedRuntime>` configuration element can contain optional attribute sku. I understood totally how to use it, but what is SKU? I mean is it an acronym and if it is, what does it stands for?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15566770/full-form-of-sku-in-supportedruntime-in-c-sharp and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17148496/what-does-sku-attribute-mean-in-c?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[SKU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stock_keeping_unit) stands for Stock Keeping Unit

> SKU refers to a stock-keeping unit, a unique identifier for each
>   distinct product and service that can be purchased in business.

**Addition info:-** You can get the list of all SKU at:-

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\SKUs
```

Answer (score 6):

SKU (stockkeeping unit) is an identification, usually alphanumeric, of a particular product that allows it to be tracked for inventory purposes. Typically, an SKU is associated with any purchasable item in a store or catalog. For example, a woman's blouse of a particular style and size might have an SKU of "3736-9," meaning "Style 3736, size 9." The SKU identification for a product may or may not be made visible to a customer. SKU numbers can sometimes be seen in online e-commerce sites.